# Which version of mysql2 is supported with Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, mysql2

i'm using Sequelize 6.6.2 with mysql2 2.2.5 to run a ClearDB database with Heroku. When testing locally with a local database, all was fine, but now I have a DeprecationWarning from Sequelize :

> (node:72340) [SEQUELIZE0006] DeprecationWarning: This database engine
> version is not supported, please update your database server. More
> information https:/
> /github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/ENGINE.md

There isn't any version specified for mysql2 so I don't know if I need to change something ? I'm not really sure why is mysql2 recommend over mysql. Despite this warning, all is working fine. Thank you for your help !

Comment: If you look at [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/ENGINE.md) you see the minimal supported versions.  From a MySQL client you can use `SELECT @@version;` to determine which version of MySQL you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAWSDB change ClearDB

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32202622)